# Annotation validations do not stop the submission of a form (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Class (that is called Membership) that has 4 properties. 3 of these properties are not all required, but at least one of them has to be filled in. I created an annotation that is working as expected (I checked it with the debugger) as it is returning a validation error message, but the UI will simply not stop the submission of the form.

This is the Membership class which has the annotation (RequiredIf)

```
public class Membership
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), Name = nameof(Name))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), Name = nameof(DaysActive))]
    [RequiredIf(nameof(MonthsActive), nameof(YearsActive), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorDays")]
    public int? DaysActive { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), Name = nameof(MonthsActive))]
    [RequiredIf(nameof(DaysActive), nameof(YearsActive), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorMonths")]
    public int? MonthsActive { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), Name = nameof(YearsActive))]
    [RequiredIf(nameof(DaysActive), nameof(MonthsActive), ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MembershipResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorYears")]
    public int? YearsActive { get; set; }
}
```

this would be the annotation that I made for it:

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string[] dependentProperties;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(params string[] dependentProperties)
    {
        this.dependentProperties = dependentProperties;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var notNullProps = 0;
            foreach (var dependentProperty in dependentProperties)
            {
                var dependentPropertyValue = validationContext.ObjectInstance?.GetType()?
                    .GetProperty(dependentProperty)?
                    .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dependentPropertyValue?.ToString()))
                {
                    notNullProps++;
                }
            }

            if (notNullProps == 0)
            {
                if (ErrorMessageResourceType != null && ErrorMessageResourceName != null) 
                {
                    var errorProperty = ErrorMessageResourceType.GetProperty(ErrorMessageResourceName);
                    if (errorProperty != null)
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult((string?)errorProperty.GetValue(null, null));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

this would be the Model for the view:

```
public class CreateMembershipViewModel
{
    public Membership Membership { get; set; }
}
```

this would be the form for creating a membership:

```
<form asp-controller="Membership" asp-action="Add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Membership.Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Membership.Name" class="form-control" required />
            <span asp-validation-for="Membership.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Membership.DaysActive"></label>
            <input asp-for="Membership.DaysActive" class="form-control" type="number" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Membership.DaysActive" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Membership.MonthsActive"></label>
            <input asp-for="Membership.MonthsActive" class="form-control" type="number" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Membership.MonthsActive" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Membership.YearsActive"></label>
            <input asp-for="Membership.YearsActive" class="form-control" type="number" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Membership.YearsActive" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">@CommonResources.Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I also tried putting the annotation (a slightly different one) in the Model, but it still would not stop the submission of empty values for the days/months/year. I also cannot put required for all those 3 fields because then it would force me to fill in all of them.

Comment: If you want the UI will simply stop the submission of the form, you need to use the IClientModelValidator interface to validate this attribute on the client side. The IClientModelValidator interface has a method called AddValidation that allows us to perform validation on the client side. Next, we need to use JQuery to implement validation for this attribute on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the custom validation attribute, implement the [IClientModelValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.iclientmodelvalidator?view=aspnetcore-7.0) interface and create an AddValidation method. In the AddValidation method, add `data-` attributes for validation as follows, below is a work demo based on your code, you can refer to it:

```
public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute,IClientModelValidator
{
    private readonly string[] dependentProperties;

    public RequiredIfAttribute(params string[] dependentProperties)
    {
        this.dependentProperties = dependentProperties;
    }
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
      var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName());
      MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
      MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest", errorMessage);
    
      MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest-propertyname", dependentProperties.First());
      MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-anothertest-desiredvalue", dependentProperties.Last());
     }

     private static bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
     {
      if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
      {
          return false;
      }
      attributes.Add(key, value);

      return true;
      }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            var notNullProps = 0;
            foreach (var dependentProperty in dependentProperties)
            {
                var dependentPropertyValue = validationContext.ObjectInstance?.GetType()?
                    .GetProperty(dependentProperty)?
                    .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dependentPropertyValue?.ToString()))
                {
                    notNullProps++;
                }
            }

            if (notNullProps == 0)
            {
                if (ErrorMessageResourceType != null && ErrorMessageResourceName != null) 
                {
                    var errorProperty = ErrorMessageResourceType.GetProperty(ErrorMessageResourceName);
                    if (errorProperty != null)
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult((string?)errorProperty.GetValue(null, null));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Then in the view add below code after form , to add a method to jQuery validation library. It uses `addMethod()` method to specify our own validation function. The validation function receives the value entered in the 3 of these properties textbox. It then performs the validation and returns a boolean value:

```
@section scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
    <script>
        $.validator.addMethod("anothertest",
            function (value, element, parameters) {
                var propertyname = $(element).data('val-anothertest-propertyname');
                var desiredvalue = $(element).data('val-anothertest-desiredvalue');
                var id1 = "Membership_" + propertyname;
                var val1 = document.getElementById(id1).value;
                var id2 = "Membership_" + desiredvalue;
                var val2 = document.getElementById(id2).value;
                if ((value == "") && (val1=="") && (val2=="")) {
                    return false
                }
                else {
                    return true
                }
            });

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("anothertest");



       
    </script>
}
```

result:

[image]

You can read [IClientModelValidator for client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#iclientmodelvalidator-for-client-side-validation) to know more.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! If I may ask, what did you write in that _ValidationScriptsPartial? And how am I supposed to use that function for the fields that I want to have that validation? I couldn't manage to make it work like yours does in the gif. Thanks again

Comment: Hi @EasyPeasy ,  I write `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.12/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>`  in t _ValidationScriptsPartial.  You can have a look at [Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation) to know more.

Comment: Hi @EasyPeasy , any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi! It seems to be working properly now. Thank you